# При использовании html() для копирования в jQuery пропадает родительский элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, frontend

Есть таблица, откуда нужно скопировать первый элемент и вывести его в другой блок. Делаю так

```
var temp = $('.temp');
var hum = $('.hum')
$("#last-temp").html(temp[0])
$("#last-hum").html(hum[0])
```

И при этом значения из таблицы .temp пропадают, но в блок #last-temp вставляются. Как сделать чтобы значения сохранилось в таблице?

Comment: html - это перезапись содержимого , но не по факту а визуально

Comment: А какой функцией копировать содержимое тогда?

Comment: insertAfter/insertBefore - то есть вставить до или после  чего то